# Unable to use Shared folder from Windows 10 to boot2docker VM after boot2docker v18.06

Tags: windows, boot2docker, docker-toolbox

I used boot2docker-v18.06.0 and I could use the shared folder in boot2docker shell which I could access windows'users folder in boot2docker. However, for boot2docker version after 18.06.xx they do not support AUFS, I could not access windows'users folder.

** Every boot2docker configs are also the default config from docker-toolbox.

Is there any way to mount shared folder into boot2docker after version 18.06 ?

refs: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/1326

Answer (score 0):

After research and trying, I can mount the shared files manually. But I have to mount the files every time while the boot2docker machine is restarted.

To mount the Users shared folder, run command in cmd:

```
docker-machine ssh <machine_name> sudo mkdir -p /c/Users
docker-machine ssh <machine_name> sudo mount -t vboxsf c/Users /c/Users
```

reference: http://support.divio.com/en/articles/646695-how-to-use-a-directory-outside-c-users-with-docker-toolbox-docker-for-windows